# Legal heir of my deceased unmarried uncle

Tags: property, india, inheritance

My dad and my uncle are the only 2 children of my grand parents. My uncle and my dad passed away before few years. Me, my sister and my mother are the legal heirs of my dad.

My uncle was unmarried . He have a house property to his name. My grand parents (My Dad's father & Mother) are also no more with us. Now who is the legal heir to the property of my Uncle ? How to proceed in the property name transfer.

Edit : Property is a residential house. Me and my sister are the surviving family members and we live in Tamil Nadu. My grand mother passed away in 2000, my grandfather in 2016, my uncle in 2016 and my dad passed away in 2020.
There is no will left by any of them.

Comment: What religion(s) were the deceased? Is there any agricultural land involved? In what state(s) do the surviving family members live?

Comment: Also: in what order did your uncle, father, grandmother and grandfather pass? And did any of them leave a valid will?This information may be important in determining the final distribution of your uncle's property.

Comment: My family follow Islam. It isn't agricultural land it is residential house. Me and my sister are the surviving family members and we live in Tamil Nadu. My grand mother passed away in 2000, my grandfather in 2016, my uncle in 2016 and my dad passed away in 2020. There is no will left by any of them.

Comment: @JafferSheriff Sunni or Shia?

Comment: We belong to Sunni

Comment: @DaleM how does sunni/shia matters in it?

Comment: @shivankgtm because inheritance is different